# get sum of integer from array of objects in mongodb

Tags: mongodb

I want to filter my documents by sum of decimal field in array of objects, but didn't find anything good enough. for example I have documents like below:

```json
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "limit": NumberDecimal("100000"),
        "requests": [
            {
                "money": NumberDecimal("50000"),
                "user": "user1"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "limit": NumberDecimal("100000"),
        "requests": [
            {
                "money": NumberDecimal("100000"),
                "user": "user2"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": 1,
        "limit": null,
        "requests": [
            {
                "money": NumberDecimal("50000"),
                "user": "user1"
            },
            {
                "money": NumberDecimal("50000"),
                "user": "user3"
            }
        ]
    },
]
```

*description by documents fields:*

1. limit - maximum amount of money, that I have
2. requests - array of objects, where money it's how much money user get from limit (if user1 get 50000 money there remainder it's 50000, limit - sum(requests.money))

*I am making query in mongodb from scala projects:*

1. get all documents where limit equal to null
2. get all documents where I have x remainder money (x like input value)

first case it's more easy than second one, I know how I can get sum of requests.money: I am doing it by this query:

```
db.campaign.aggregate([
    {$project: {
        total: {$sum: ["$requests.money"]}
    }}
])
```

scala filter part

```scala
Filters.or(
    Filters.equal("limit", null),
    Filters.expr(Document(s""" {$$project: {total: {$$sum: ["$$requests.money"]}}}"""))
)
```

But I don't want to store it and get as result, I want to filter by this condition **x** (money which I want to get by some user) *limit >= sum(requests.money) + x*. And by this filter I want to get all filtered documents.

**Example:**
x = 50000
and output must be like this:

```json
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "limit": NumberDecimal("100000"),
        "requests": [
            {
                "money": NumberDecimal("50000"),
                "user": "user1"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": 1,
        "limit": null,
        "requests": [
            {
                "money": NumberDecimal("50000"),
                "user": "user1"
            },
            {
                "money": NumberDecimal("50000"),
                "user": "user3"
            }
        ]
    },
]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use an aggregation pipeline like this:

```
db.campaign.aggregate([
  {
    $set: {
      remainder: {
        $subtract: [ "$limit", { $sum: "$requests.money" } ]
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$match": {
      $or: [
        { limit: null },
        { remainder: { $gte: 0 } }
      ]
    }
  },
  { $unset: "remainder" }
])
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/eD-TeUuKv21)

This one is also possible, but more difficult to read:

```
db.campaign.aggregate([
  {
    "$match": {
      $or: [
        { limit: null },
        {
          $expr: {
            $gt: [
              { $subtract: [ "$limit", { $sum: "$requests.money" } ] },
              0
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
])
```